# .htaccess redirect when one domain is a subset of the other

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect, subdomain

Sorry, I wasn't sure how to word the title correctly.

I have a few domains which I want to 301 redirect to my primary domain using .htaccess.

This is what I'm doing:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.co.za [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://primarydomain.co.za/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I'm having an issue redirecting a .co domains to a similar .co.za domains, eg:

```
// this causes infinite loop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.co.za/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I get why this is happening but I don't  know how to write that rule or its condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pattern anchors: `^` and `$` to mark the beginning or end (respectively) of your strings:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.co.za%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about the delay in replying back here. I've accepted this anwer because it explained the anchors to me..

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.co.za/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative condition and avoid regex:

```
# if host is not example.co.za
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.co.za
# then redirect to example.co.za
RewriteRule ^ http://example.co.za%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```